# How to implement polymorphism in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, data-modeling

There seems to be concepts of implementing polymorphism with MongoDB but I can't find any good documentation on how to do it.

Can I do this as part of MongoDB itself - or do I have to model it in Mongoose ( I use Nodejs )

To give an example of the type of data I want to store/ retrieve, I want to store 2 types of products in a product collection.  Simple and Grouped.

**Both types** will have

- _id
- sku
- name

**Grouped products** will have

- associated_ids an array of id's to link to simple products
- meta_name
- meta_description

**Simple Products** will have

- buy_price
- sell_price

Is there a good data modelling program for MongoDB as well?

If someone can point me in the right direction, I don't think I am looking in the right place.

Thanks
Martin

Comment: MongoDB [Data Model Introduction](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/data-modeling-introduction/).

Comment: I am also interested in using a polymorphic schema in MongoDB but I don't see any helpful answers here. Is StackOverflow only for debugging or small problems/ If so, fine. But a cursory search does not reveal any simple or free tutorials on how to do what is being asked here. Not fun running into a dead end when trying to grow skill sets.

Answer (score -3):

Example of usage MongoDb Polymorphism [here](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.0/reference/bson/mapping/polymorphism/).

You may find out course "Data Modeling" of [MongoDb University](https://university.mongodb.com/courses/catalog) helpful. There are lectures "Schema Versioning Pattern" and "Polymorphic Pattern" gives some steps of modeling polymorphism in MongoDb.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30452562)